# How to conduct PCA on each group for a dataset with multiple groups?

Tags: r, pca, princomp

I have a dataset of individuals from four populations, four treatments and three replicates. Each individual is in only one population, treatment and replicate combination. I have taken four measurements from each individual. I would like to conduct a PCA on these measurement for each population, substrate, and replicate combination.

I am aware of how to do a PCA on all individuals and I can split the dataset into multiple datasets for each combination of population, substrate, and replicate and then perform the PCA on each new dataset.

How can I conduct a PCA on the complete dataset getting separate PC1, PC2... results for each combination of population, substrate, and replicate the most efficiently? I have a thought about converting the dataset to a list, but unsure how to apply the princomp function to a list. Am I on the right track?

Sample data:

```
TestData<- structure(list(Location = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                                   "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                                   "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
                                   "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"),
              Substrate = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D",
                            "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D",
                            "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D",
                            "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
              Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
              Adult_Weight = c(0.0092, 0.0083, 0.0088, 0.0077, 0.0088, 0.01, 
                               0.0099, 0.011, 0.0078, 0.0086, 0.0071, 0.0093, 
                               0.0111, 0.01, 0.0097, 0.0091, 0.0083, 0.0098,
                               0.0093, 0.009, 0.0114, 0.0087, 0.0094, 0.0096, 
                               0.0099, 0.0105, 0.0091, 0.0115, 0.0106, 0.0104, 
                               0.0113, 0.0115, 0.0107, 0.0126, 0.0106, 0.0101,
                               0.0095, 0.0113, 0.0111, 0.0118, 0.0114, 0.0123, 
                               0.0119, 0.0103, 0.0119, 0.0116, 0.0112, 0.0114), 
              Adult_Thorax_Width = c(1.31, 1.31, 1.43, 1.45, 1.52, 1.43, 1.57, 1.45, 1.43, 1.54, 1.32, 1.49, 
                                     1.58, 1.36, 1.42, 1.45, 1.48, 1.38, 1.55, 1.46, 1.52, 1.42, 1.6, 1.49, 
                                     1.48, 1.58, 1.51, 1.53, 1.54, 1.76, 1.63, 1.62, 1.44, 1.51, 1.53, 1.58, 
                                     1.46, 1.94, 1.54, 2.09, 1.5, 1.65, 1.86, 1.54, 1.8, 1.98, 1.82, 1.63), 
              Adult_Wing_Length = c(1359L, 1377L, 1555L, 1559L, 1562L, 1578L, 1580L, 1588L, 1597L, 1598L, 1603L, 1605L, 
                                    1612L, 1614L, 1616L, 1617L, 1623L, 1628L, 1639L, 1642L, 1643L, 1649L, 1651L, 1652L, 
                                    1653L, 1653L, 1654L, 1656L, 1656L, 1656L, 1662L, 1664L, 1665L, 1668L, 1670L, 1670L, 
                                    1671L, 1672L, 1674L, 1682L, 1685L, 1687L, 1688L, 1694L, 1698L, 1698L, 1707L, 1708L), 
              Adult_Leg_Length = c(414L, 390L, 627L, 541L, 430L, 450L, 451L, 462L, 443L, 582L, 435L, 579L, 
                                   499L, 418L, 444L, 646L, 589L, 466L, 435L, 477L, 450L, 606L, 660L, 450L, 
                                   446L, 480L, 462L, 438L, 483L, 454L, 492L, 457L, 463L, 499L, 470L, 474L, 
                                   627L, 478L, 473L, 496L, 666L, 499L, 480L, 461L, 450L, 483L, 460L, 584L)),
              .Names = c("Location", "Substrate", "Replicate", "Weight", "Thorax_Width", "Wing_Length", "Leg_Length"),
              row.names = c(NA, 48L), 
              class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you provide a dummy dataset, I'll show you how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should input your population and treatments as factorial variables, and have the three replicates as separate rows, if I understood your data composition correctly. Column types would be something like:

- 1st column population: factor
- 2nd column treatment: factor
- 3rd - 6th column measurement: numeric (total 4 columns)

And the overall data class should be preferably '*data.frame*', because in '*data.frame*' your columns may have different class types (unlike in '*matrix*' for example).

Here is an example that stratifies the example Iris-dataset according to a factorial variable, here '*iris$Species*'. If you have multiple factors that you want to stratify for, you could use a two (or more) columned matrix as an input for the *INDICES* argument. Are you sure you don't really mean a single PCA with annotations though? This could be easily be done by changing your factor-type variables to numbers and annotate them in the scatterplot e.g. through '*col*' (=color) and '*pch*' (=symbol) parameters.

```
data(iris) # Load the example Iris-dataset
class(iris)
lapply(iris, FUN=class)
#> class(iris)
#[1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> lapply(iris, FUN=class)
#$Sepal.Length
#[1] "numeric"
#
#$Sepal.Width
#[1] "numeric"
#
#$Petal.Length
#[1] "numeric"
#
#$Petal.Width
#[1] "numeric"
#
#$Species
#[1] "factor"

par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(4,4,2,1))
# Separate PCA plot for each Species
# Apply our defined PCA-function where each unique INDICES are handled as a separate function call
by(iris, INDICES=iris$Species, FUN=function(z){
    # Use numeric fields for the PCA
    pca <- prcomp(z[,unlist(lapply(z, FUN=class))=="numeric"])
    plot(pca$x[,1:2], pch=16, main=z[1,"Species"]) # 2 first principal components
    z
})

# Color annotation
# Use numeric fields for the PCA
pca <- prcomp(iris[,unlist(lapply(iris, FUN=class))=="numeric"])
plot(pca$x[,1:2], pch=16, col=as.numeric(iris[,"Species"]), main="Color annotation") # 2 first principal components
legend("bottom", pch=16, col=unique(as.numeric(iris[,"Species"])), legend=unique(iris[,"Species"]))
```

[image: PCA example]

Notice that the PCA-axes are not the same in the first three panels counting from top-left. This is due to the fact that the covariance matrix in the PCA computation is not the same when computing only group-wise PCAs.

Alternatively, if you want a single PCA, but just plot the observations belonging to different categories in their own windows, you could try something in the lines of:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
# Compute the PCA
pca <- prcomp(iris[,unlist(lapply(iris, FUN=class))=="numeric"])
# Apply a plotting function over unique values of iris$Species, notice we always plot the same 'pca' object in all categories
lapply(unique(iris$Species), FUN=function(z) { 
    plot(pca$x[which(z==iris$Species),1:2], xlim=extendrange(pca$x[,1]), ylim=extendrange(pca$x[,2]),pch=16, main=z)
})
```

[image: pca2]

EDIT:

Out of the help file of the '*by*'-function:
"INDICES: a factor or a list of factors, each of length nrow(data)."

Thus, we can stratify the data in respect to multiple factorial variables if we provide the indices within a list to the *by*-function. Here is an artificial example, where 'first' and 'second' are two simultaneous factors that stratify the data. This should be trivial to extend to three (or more) variables:

```
ex <- cbind(matrix(rnorm(400), ncol=4), first = c("A", "B"), second = c("foo", "bar", "asd", "fgh", "jkl"))
by(ex, INDICES=list(ex[,"first"], ex[,"second"]), FUN=function(z) z)
# Modify the above function provided in FUN to suit your needs
```

Comment: I have now included some sample data. The third column is also a factor and that is the replicate number. Columns 4:7 are the measurements.

Comment: I see how use are using the "by" command to build a function that performs the PCA on a single variable "Species". How might I do this for three variables, Location, Substrate, Replicate? Of course I can create a new variable that merges these three fields, but is their a better way to do it?

Comment: Hello Keith, yup 'by' stratifies the data in respect to one or more factorial variables. I now edited my post above with an example where an artificial data is split by two factorial variables. Yours is going to be a list of three variables where each member of the list is one of the vectors of 'Location', 'Substrate', or 'Replicate'.